# how to set the x-axis of barplot

Tags: r, plot

This has been questioned many times like this one [X axis in Barplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595452/x-axis-in-barplot-in-r)

however none helped me to solve my problem

```
dt<- structure(c(79L, 54L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 121L, 134L, 169L, 23L, 19L, 
22L, 19L, 25L), .Names = c("Experi_1", "Experi_2", "Experi_3", 
"Experi_4", "Experi_5", "Experi_6", "Experi_7", "Experi_8", "Experi_9", 
"Experi_10", "Experi_11", "Experi_12", "Experi_13"))
```

I plot my data like this

```
mydt<- barplot(dt)
```

if I do this , it overlay twice the x-axis

```
axis(side=1,at=mydt[1+c(1,13)],labels=c("Experi1","Experi13"))
```

It set few of the x-axis labels automatically. I want to do it manually, for example get only mention beginning of x-axis label and end . In this case Experi1 and Experi 13. I tried to understand *?axis* and specially *label* but I could not set it to a costume as axis label as I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Parameter `names.arg` of `barplot` function allows you to custom your labels the way you want. You just have to give the parameter a vector of name with the same length as the number of bars:

for example, putting only first and last:

```
barplot(dt, names.arg=c("Experi_1", rep("", 11), "Experi_13"))
```

[image]

another example, putting 5 labels:

```
barplot(dt, names.arg=c(names(dt)[1:5], rep("", 2), names(dt)[8:13]))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

if you want to put label by sequence (every 5 for the example), you can do:

```
lab <- rep("", length(dt))
lab[seq(1, length(dt), by=5)] <-names(dt)[seq(1, length(dt), by=5)]
barplot(dt, names.arg=lab)
```

[image]

Comment: You may have to rotate the labels, either with par las or with a separate writing with mtext

Comment: Then you'll have to "play" with mar probably

Comment: thank you, so if you find any solution, please let me know

Answer (score 3):

I think this should give you what you want:

```
mydt<- barplot(dt,xaxt='n')
axis(side=1,at=mydt[c(1,13)],labels=c("Experi1","Experi13"))
```

You need to suppress the x axis by using `xaxt='n'` and remove `1+` from the `at` argument.

Comment: xaxt will remove my caption too, so I don't think it is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if there are a lot of bars, barplot() automatically decides which ones will be printed, being not necessarily our selection. I solved this problem filling the labels with NA's instead of "". That is:

```
    lab <- rep(NA, length(dt))
    lab[seq(1, length(dt), by=5)] <-names(dt)[seq(1, length(dt), by=5)]
    barplot(dt, names.arg=lab)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had data over a 60 year time series and wanted to order them every 5 years using names.arg. I simply added a column which gave me the years I wanted to plot on the x axis.

For example

`df$YearX<- c("1990", "","","","", "1995".....)`
This added a column to my data frame with the correct years and spaces between to plot on my graph.

Then simply plotted this as my x axis using `names.arg=df$YearX` in my barplot

It was much quicker for me for some reason. The names appeared every 5 years.

Hope this helps someone.