# fit labels in R barplot

Tags: r, plot

I have a df: `recipeCategoryDF` with two columns `WORD`, `FREQ` like below (ordered ascending)

```
               WORD FREQ
14         bulgaars    1
57       tsjechisch    1
6        argentijns    2
27          indisch    2
50           schots    2
60       vietnamees    2
32    joegoslavisch    3
44            pools    3
47         russisch    4
7       australisch    5
25             iers    5
......
```

I want to plot a horizontal barplot, so I do:

```
barplot(height=recipeCategoryDF$FREQ, names = recipeCategoryDF$WORD, horiz = TRUE, xlab = 'COUNT',
        las=1, cex.names=0.7, xlim = c(0, 1100), 
        xaxs='r')
```

Now I have two questions

Q1. There are some longer labels which I would like to fit on the graph e.g. `goedkoop-en-snel` (please see image) but they get cropped on the left side. With the `xaxs` argument I have been able to create some space and have reduced font size. I have played around with a lot of other `par` functions like `mar`, but I still cannot fit the labels.

Q2. How can I change the ticks, now they are at intervals of 200, I have looked at some answers like: [how to set the x-axis of barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330396/how-to-set-the-x-axis-of-barplot) and it is not working for me[image]

Comment: To have the labels fully displayed increase the margins around the plot. For example,  `par(mar = c(3,8,3,3)`, which sets the margin on the left side of the plot to `8`

Comment: As to your second question: are fewer labels shown than you have bars? (It doesn't  look like that.)

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, the margins are working with your solution. I tried with ```mar=c(5,4,4,2)``` and it was not successful. How did you determine that ```c(3,8,3,3)``` would work?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann for every label I see there is a bar

Comment: `par(mar = c(3,8,3,3)` works, as you say, because `mar` works clockwise: the first number is for the x-axis, the second number is for the y-axis and so on.